# background images repeat-x in iOS does not working

Tags: html, ios, css, image, mobile

Hi i working on this site http://sealonline.playrohan.com/main.html#&slider1=3

it seemed fine in the web browser but in mobile it looks different.

problem 1.
footer's background images repeat-x is not working.

```
div.load    {height:12px; width:100%; background:url('/image/seal_common/footer_pt.gif') 0 0 repeat-x;}
```

problem2.
images is cut it out.
the villige image is more wide but is not showing.

```
div.villige {height: 124px; width:100%; text-align:center; background:url('/image/seal_common/bg_footer.png') 0 0 no-repeat bottom; display: block;}
```

problem 3.
middle section is not in the middle.
i already put this.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

but it still doesn't work.

This is first web site using html 5.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ask one question at a time. These three things are different issues, with different solutions, and should be answered individually.

Answer (score 0):

can you try replacing your body css property `margin: 0;` to `margin: 0 auto;` first? then add some other styles to your body tag:

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
max-width: <the max width of your background image>;
```

let me know what happens next.